# "--async-stack-traces" nodejs flag in jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I just downloaded the latest nodejs version, which amazingly supports the "--async-stack-traces" flat to show the stack trace-back of Errors that occur in async functions.

It works for me when I use my own website, but when I run my jest tests the async errors still do not show their stack. Is there any way I can change it (when I try to run Jest as "react-scripts test --runInBand --async-stack-traces" it says that async-stack-traces is an invalid flag.

Answer (score 1):

To pass custom flags to node, you'll need to explicitly invoke jest with node:

```sh
node --async-stack-traces node_modules/.bin/jest #[ANY JEST ARGUMENTS HERE]
```

Alternatively if (like me) you prefer not to hardcode `node_modules` paths, you can use `npx` to invoke jest with custom node flags:

```sh
npx -n --async-stack-traces jest #[ANY JEST ARGUMENTS HERE]
```

An example `package.json` might look like:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "npx -n --async-stack-traces jest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --bad-node-arg node_modules/.bin/jest"
}
```

I found answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/549#issuecomment-280080769)